# Type of union of disjunct functions?

Tags: type-theory

Given two functions:

```
f :: EvenInteger -> {0}
g :: OddInteger -> {1}
```

consider the function

```
h = (x :: Integer) => {
    if(x is even)return f(x);
    return g(x);
}
```

What the smallest type T such that

```
h :: T
```

I was thinking that it is simply

```
h :: (typeof f) & (typeof g)
```

But then I would also think that a function call distributes over conjunction i.e., that

```
x :: EvenInteger
h(x) :: (typeof f(x)) & (typeof g(x))
```

which begs another question:

What is

```
(OddInteger -> {1})(EvenInteger)
```